# Deploy Spring project to apache tomcat8 with intellij

Tags: java, spring, apache, tomcat, intellij-idea

please don't mind that I ask a simple question.

I'm a newbie to Spring in particular with IntelliJ.
I'm trying to deploy a HelloWorld project to apache tomcat with IntelliJ.

I have a generated index.jsp in a folder called /web with the following content

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>$Title$</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  $END$
  </body>
</html>
```

I also created a simple controller with the following content

```
package main;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
/**
 * Handles requests for the application home page.
 */
@Controller
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String home() {
        System.out.println("HomeController: Passing through...");
        return "index.jsp";
    }
}
```

I can compile the project using make, but when I try to open

> http://localhost:8080/home

I get a 404 error.

So how can I configure IntelliJ to deploy my HelloWorld-App to the apache tomcat server?

Comment: i think it's better to do it using tools like maven, gradle, cause you can do it easily and not be dependend to the IDE.

Comment: Try to post  the web.xml, and what is home? and file spring xml

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Create Project

Select Spring Project (If you don't want to use Spring Boot)

Give name to your project

[Edit Configurations to add Tomcat Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aX1uT.png)

Select Tomcat Server -> Local from Menu

[Point to Tomcat Directory and add artifact to deploy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvSBm.png)

Right-click on the project and select 'Open Module Setting'

On the right-hand side of the split-pane click "+" and add 'Library Files'

Select both Spring and Spring MVC to add to artifact

Now run your app and go to localhost:8080 in your browser. It should display $END$

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thnx! This was the best answer so far. I added a local tomcat8 server in the deploy-options. It works except that when I try to run it, it says that it found no server.xml in the .IntelliJIdea15/system/tomcat/Unnamed_Form/conf directory. How can I fix this?

Comment: So I fixed the server.xml issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34981233/inellij-and-apache-tomcat8-found-no-server-xml-in-the-intellijidea15-system-tom

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to Spring I would recommend first learning it(by 'it' I mean the overall application flow, controllers, services, database access etc.) using Spring Boot. It configures everything for you and comes with embedded Tomcat. All you have to do is run the application as if it were a plain Java project.

Otherwise you might get discouraged quickly, as Spring + Maven configuration tends to be big and not newbie-friendly.