# InelliJ and apache tomcat8 found no server.xml in the .IntelliJIdea15/system/tomcat/Unnamed_Form/conf directory

Tags: xml, apache, tomcat, configuration, tomcat8

I stumbled over an error with my tomcat8-installation. I installed apache tomcat8 on Ubuntu 15.10 from the package list.

For some reason it didn't install the configuration-files "server.xml" and "web.xml" in the

> /usr/share/tomcat8/conf

directory

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to fix it:
Download the full [tomcat8-Core-tar.gz](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-80.cgi) from here:

[Download](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-80.cgi)

Then open the

> /apache-tomcat-8.0.x/conf/

directory and copy server.xml- and web.xml-files to

> /usr/share/tomcat8/conf

enjoy.